# Magento 2.0.2 is automatically redirecting to localhost on live server

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Can any one help me here ?

After uploading magento 2.0.2 files to live server and import database to PHPMYAdmin now index is automatically redirecting to localhost where files has been transferred. I know it need to be change the URL path but didn't get the right place, In magento 1.9 changing path in database table (core_config_data table) but how to change the right path in magento 2.0.2 ?

Your help will be appreciated :)
Thanx

Comment: At least found it, redirecting has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

I know you fixed it, but here my solution, maybe it helps others:
When you go from local to live, you switch your Domain and need to tell Magento about it. An easy way to do that is on CLI:

```
# http:// or https://, and a trailing slash /.
./bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://your-domain.com/"
./bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://your-domain.com/"

# clear cache
./bin/magento cache:flush
```